# Is there a way to add link to apps script functions in the doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In my doc I want to add hyperlinks to do specific actions in my doc using apps script.
I need this to add a link at the end of the line item, that can change the color of the line item in the doc.

For e.g:
If my doc has the following line item:

The line item ([black](http://stackoverflow.com) [blue](http://stackoverflow.com) [green](http://stackoverflow.com))

where the black, blue and green change the color of the line item.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, "link_text").setLinkUrl("url_to_visit");
```

Or `DocumentApp.openById("<my-id>").getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, "link_text").setLinkUrl("url_to_visit"); //replace Id`